# sh: can't return one result after comparing 2 files

Tags: sh, ksh

as an example I will put different inputs to keep the privacy of my files and to avoid long text, these are of the following form :

INPUT1.cfg :

```
TC      # aa      #  D317    
TC      # bb      #  D314    
TC      # cc      #  D315  
TC      # dd      #  D316
```

INPUT2.cfg

```
BL;nn;3
LY;ww;3
LO;xx;3
TC;vv;3
TC;dd;3
OD;pp;3
TC;aa;3
```

what I want to do is iterate the name (column 2) in the rows of input1 and compare with the name (column 2) in the rows of input2; if they match we will get the line of INPUT2 in an output file otherwise it will return that the table is not found, here is my try code:

```
#!/bin/bash

input1="input1.cfg";
input2="input2.cfg"

cat $input1|while read line 
do
    TableNameIN=`echo $line|cut -d"#" -f2`
    cat $input2| while read line
    do
        TableNameOUT=`echo $line|cut -d";" -f2`
        if  echo "$TableNameOUT" | grep -q $TableNameIN;
            then echo "$line" >> output.txt
            
        else
            echo "Table $TableNameIN non trouvé"
        fi
        
    done
done
```

this what i get as result :

```
Table  bb not found
Table  bb not found
Table  bb not found
Table  cc not found
Table  cc not found
Table  cc not found
```

I manage to write what is equal but the problem with my code is that it has in output "table not found" for each row whereas I just want to write only once at the end of the comparison of all the lines

here is the output i want to get :

```
Table  bb not found
Table  cc not found
```

Can any one help me with this , PS : I don't want to use awk because it's just a part of my code and i already use sh

Comment: you've tagged the question with both `sh` and `ksh`, but mention `bash` and `sh` in the question; which shell are you using?  please update the question's tags to match with the shell you're actually using; if you won't use `awk` then consider storing the 'not found' table names in an array, then after the looping is done you loop through the array of 'not found' tables and print the message

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- for file `input2.cfg` the 2nd column (table name) is unique
- `input2.cfg` is not so large that we run the risk of using up all memory for storing `intput2.cfg` in an associative array (otherwise we could store the table names from `input1.cfg`'s - assuming this is a smaller file - in the array and swap the processing order of the two files)
- there are no explicit requirements for data to be sorted (otherwise we may need to add a `sort` or two)
- a `bash` solution is sufficient (based on inclusion of the `#!/bin/bash` shebang in OPs current code)

There are many ways to slice-n-dice this one (`awk` being my preference but OP doesn't want to use `awk`).  For this particular answer I'll pull the `awk` steps out into separate `bash` commands.

**NOTE**: While we could use a set of nested loops (as in the OPs code), I've opted to use an associative array to store `input2.cfg` thus eliminating the need to repeatedly scan `input2.cfg`.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

input1=input1.cfg
input2=input2.cfg

> output.txt                                          # clear out the target file

# load ${input2} into an associative array

unset lines
typeset -A lines                                      # associative array for storing contents of ${input2}

while read -r line
do
    x="${line%;*}"                                    # use parameter expansion
    tabname="${x#*;}"                                 # to parse out table name

    lines["${tabname}"]="${line}"                     # add to array
done < "${input2}"

# process ${input1}

while read -r c1 c2 tabname rest_of_line
do
    [[ -v lines["${tabname}"] ]]              &&      # if tabname has an entry in our array
    echo "${lines[${tabname}]}" >> output.txt &&      # then dump the associated line (from ${input2}) to output.txt
    continue                                          # process next line from ${input1}

    echo "Table ${tabname} not found"                 # otherwise print 'not found' message
done < "${input1}"

# display contents of output.txt

echo "++++++++++++++++ output.txt"
cat output.txt
echo "++++++++++++++++"
```

This generates the following:

```
Table bb not found
Table cc not found
++++++++++++++++ output.txt
TC;aa;3
TC;dd;3
++++++++++++++++
```